# Pandas dataframe. Group by value and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:

```
Days, Age,  Sex

5,    39,   F
4,    54,   M
4,    26,   M
5,    42,   M
4,    29,   M
```

I want to count number of rows with F and M separately. The following command works, but I'm not OK with the representation:

```
df.groupby("Sex").count()
```

What will be the best way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: What “representation” are you looking for?

Comment: df.groupby("Sex").size() ?

Comment: As for my command I got a table in Jupyter notebook with useless column. I'd like to have somathing like
Sex
F 2
M 3

Comment: @Wen, could you please put your comment df.groupby("Sex").size() as an answer? Thank you. This is what I was looking for, but couldn't figure out

Comment: @Jerry no worry ,since you got it  happy coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add to Wen's answer. Alternatively, you can use `value_counts` while selecting the column with `df.Sex`.

```
df.Sex.value_counts()
    M    4
    F    1
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```