# Need assistance with excel python data scraping assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I'm recently new to learning python (been at it for 6 weeks now) and I don't know how to attack this assignment. For the assignment we are given an excel data set from Twitter and supposed to "scrape the data".

**I'm supposed find the unique usernames and the number of times they tweeted on Twitter (excluding retweets and replies) within the dataset you have.
And find the top 10 users with the most frequent number of tweets (excluding retweets and replies).**

I've been using pandas and I can't find the correct string of code to accomplish what I need.

I was able to use this code to filter all the users who only sent a "Tweet". This seems like my only breakthrough.

```
df.loc[df['Relationship'] == "Tweet"]
```

In the dataset there is a column that has the usernames "Users1" (i.e. their twitter handles) and a column named "Relationship" (i.e. mention, replies, Tweet). Those are the two columns that I've been working with.

Unfortunately, I'm in over my head and need any assistance possible.

Thanks

Edit:

```
print(df.User1.value_counts(['Relationship'] == "Tweet"))
```

Was able to make some progress with this code ^

That's really the only string of code that I've found semi-useful. I've been spitballing for over an hour now.

I've attached a picture of a portion of the data.[Portion of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50EjV.png)

Comment: hint: try the `groupby` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas dataframe. Group by value and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253759/pandas-dataframe-group-by-value-and-count)

Comment: Please edit your question with any attempts you have made to move beyond that, and what went wrong with them. Also, please include an excerpt of your dataset.

Comment: @pydude made an edit. Added a screenshot of what my data set looks like. Thx

Comment: @Nikaidoh I tried that and still not having success

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is add a 'tweetcount' column for each User1, I think. If each linebreak represents a tweet, that just means counting the endlines ('\n') in each tweet string.

For finding unique elements in a column of data in a pandas dataframe, this should work, if you have imported numpy as np:

```
#generate a numpy array from the dataframe:
names = df[['username']].to_numpy()
#generate a simple list from the numpy array (flatten the array):
temp = [x for items in names for x in items]
#extract the unique elements from the simple list using the count method:
uniques = [x for x in temp if temp.count(x) == 1]
```

Now you have a list of unique names, to extract the index values from your pandas df:

```
indices = [x for x in range(len(df)) if df.loc[x, 'username'] in uniques]
```

To get the full row of data for each unique username:

```
for x in indices:
    print(df.loc[x, 'username'], df.loc[x, 'tweetcount'])
```

Sorting by a given column in a pandas dataframe is much simpler (and their might be a simpler solution for this as well). Just use:

```
df.sort_values(by='tweetcount')
```